# Domino Server delivering svg files with mime-type application/octet-stream

Tags: svg, lotus-domino

I have a Domino 9.0.1 Server with a static website which contains a svg file (because, you know, scalable, pretty, etc).

But the domino server is sending an HTTP header of application/octet-stream.

I have setup under Configuration/Web/File identifications a document with:

```
MIME type: image
MIME subtype: svg+xml
File extension: svg
```

but no bananas.

[image]

can you help?

Comment: Is the svg file inside a nsf?

Comment: no, the svg is within a folder /img/ within C:\Websites\Magerman in the domino server. I have a Website document pointing to that file resource.

Comment: Are you using IBM HTTP Server, or Domino's internal webserver itself?

Comment: @sjcaged, I'm just using one machine. Is that your question?

Comment: IBM HTTP Server is an Apache-based webserver that includes mod_domino, and provides TLS capabilities (which Domino itself does not have).  They can coexist on the same machine, and together are the preferred mechanism for providing web access to Domino resources.  Your response indicates that you are not using this configuration.

Comment: No, it's just the normal domino http task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The File Identification documents are used with MIME types for mail. To add a MIME type for web content, you need to edit the httpd.cnf file in the Domino data directory and refresh the HTTP task.

Answer (score 0):

In your File Identification, do you have it marked as "Outbound: Send"?

Comment: sjcaged, sorry for the delay - I'm in training right now, will answer as soon as back in the office.